# What are the products formed when nitrogen dioxide reacts with water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I've seen two different equations for the reaction of nitrogen dioxide with water:

$$\ce{2NO2 + H2O -> H+ + NO3- + HNO2}$$

and

$$\ce{3NO2 + H2O -> 2H+ + 2NO3- + NO}$$

Are both of these correct to some degree, and is one more prominent over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the reactions are correct. However, the second reaction is written by 'adding' two reaction equations.

When nitrogen dioxide($\ce{NO2}$) is dissolved in water, it produces a 1:1 mixture of nitric acid($\ce{HNO3)}$ and nitrous acid(HNO2). $$\ce{2NO2(g) +H2O(l)->HNO3(aq) +HNO2(aq)}$$
i.e.$$\ce{2NO2(g) +2H2O(l)->H3O+(aq) +NO3-(aq) + HNO2(aq)}$$

However, since nitrous acid is unstable in any environment except very cold solution, it decomposes slowly into $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$:
$$\ce{3HNO2(aq)->2NO(g) +H3O+(aq) + NO3-(aq)}$$

Your second reaction equation is obtained by adding these two reaction together.

Reference:

1. Housecroft, C. E.; Constable, E. C. *Chemistry,* 4th ed.; Pearson, 2010, p 777.

Note:

I wrote the $\ce{H+}$ ions as $\ce{H3O+}$, so there  is an extra water molecule on the left side of the equation, in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Both can take place, but [nitrous acid is unstable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrous_acid).  In warm or concentrated solutions, the nitrous acid will disproportionate, forming nitric oxide and more nitric acid.  So the nitrous acid is essentially only a temporary intermediate.